# Conda environment cannot be activate

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, google-colaboratory

I try to run a project named miniGPT-4 on Google Colab. After I installed conda, the environment cannot be activated with the following error:

```
usage: conda [-h] [--no-plugins] [-V] COMMAND ...
conda: error: argument COMMAND: invalid choice: 'activate' (choose from 'clean', 'compare', 'config', 'create', 'info', 'init', 'install', 'list', 'notices', 'package', 'remove', 'uninstall', 'rename', 'run', 'search', 'update', 'upgrade', 'doctor', 'env', 'content-trust')
```

This is the first time I met the error like this and I have no thought about this.
Besides, the entire process I installed conda is based on the tutorial above:
https://towardsdatascience.com/conda-google-colab-75f7c867a522.
I did not change anything except for the conresponding version (such as change python3.6 to python3.11, and set the conda version as the latest).

Besides, a duplicate question about conda environment on Colab recommends `condacolab`, which supports only python3.8-. Nevertheless, I tried it but received another error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell
```

Then I tried to fix this as the return but failed after run the `conda init` command:

```
no change     /usr/local/condabin/conda
no change     /usr/local/bin/conda
no change     /usr/local/bin/conda-env
no change     /usr/local/bin/activate
no change     /usr/local/bin/deactivate
no change     /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /usr/local/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /usr/local/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /usr/local/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /usr/local/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /root/.bashrc
No action taken.
```

I really hope anyone can help me to fix this problem. Many thanks!

Comment: `conda` has like-named shell script and executable program that have different roles. The executable doesn't understand "activate". This is fixed by executing `conda init` - which will put the shell script in the right place to intercept "acitvate" calls. I don't know exactly how to do that in your colab environment.

Comment: As per duplicate, it is a misconception that one can “activate” a separate Conda environment on Colab and use it in cells. Instead, Conda is used to install additional packages into the Python that is running as the iPython kernel.